# How to perform a negative lookbehind?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to perform a Regex negative look behind that will find the existence of a keyword in SQL that is not part of a comment

eg

```
-- some comments create
/* some more comments create
some more create
*/ 
create
```

only the last create keyword should match because all of the others are in comments

So far I have this

```
(?<!--.*?)(?<!/\*.*?)\bcreate\b
```

which eliminates the first two "create" words.

I need to be able to eliminate the third one by spanning over multiple lines, but then I need to match the fourth one by using an exception on the end comment (`*/`) marker

I have looked at a number of regex sites such as http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html but I am unable to work out how to do this.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35292902/edit) your post when adding informations

Comment: Not sure that `C#` implements variable length negative lookbehind.

Comment: @Toto: Yes, .NET regex supports an infinite-width lookbehind. Dave, you can just match and capture the comments, and then just match the `create` in order to perform any changes to it. See [`(--.*|/\*[^*]*\*+([^/*][^*]*\*+)*/)|\bcreate\b`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(--.*%7c%2f%5c*%5b%5e*%5d*%5c*%2b(%5b%5e%2f*%5d%5b%5e*%5d*%5c*%2b)*%2f)%7c%5cbcreate%5cb&i=--+some+comments+create%0d%0a%2f*+some+more+comments+create%0d%0asome+more+create%0d%0a*%2f+%0d%0acreate)

Comment: Wiktor's comment solved my problem.  Thanks to all the others who contributed.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<!--.*)(?<!/\*(?s:(?!\*/).)*)\bcreate\b
```

The goal with the second lookbehind is to make sure it doesn't cross over any instances of `*/` before it finds the `/*`.  The technique I'm using is called *tempered lookahead*:

```
(?s:(?!\*/).)*
```

Each time it matches a character, it first does a negative lookahead to make sure it's not the first character of the sequence you're trying to exclude.

The `s` in `(?s:` causes everything in that group to be matched in `Singleline` mode, meaning the `.` matches newlines.

Answer (score -1):

I think its easier to remove comments and this is how :

```
    // use these regex patterns

     public string RemoveSQLComments(string sqlQuery)
        {
            Regex r1 = new Regex(@"(\/\*)(?s:(?!\*\/).)*(\*\/)", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline &
                                  System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Regex r2 = new Regex("(--)[^\r\n$]*(?=(\r|\n|$))", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline &
                                  System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            return r2.Replace(r1.Replace(sqlQuery, ""), "");
        }
```

The result would be the SQL string without any comments.

Comment: Several problems here, including: (1) `(` and `)` have no special meaning in character classes, and (2) you use `|` combine options, not `&`; you got away with it because neither of those options have any effect on your regexes.  Also, there's no need to clutter the answer with full namespaces; it's okay to assume anyone asking C# questions knows how to use `using`.

Comment: Your first regex won't match a comment that contains any of the characters `(`, `*`, `/`, or `)`, like `/* (perfectly * valid / comment) */`.  What you're trying to do requires a negative lookahead, as I demonstrated in my answer: `(?s:(?!\*/).)*`.   And using `&` to combine options insures that *none* of the options will be applied.  Your regexes matched because you didn't need any options.